# Metasploit (install)

Tags: uninstall

Hey i was installing metasploit on my laptop,suddenly i accidentally remove/moved the plug. So my laptop turned off. When i reinstall metasploit, this is what i get

[image]

My question is, how can i kill or stop 7337 port to install metasploit, or maybe uninstall metasploit completely. Anyway i deleted /opt/metasploitxxx so the unistaller was gone. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the service is already running and using that port, try to kill metasploit before the reinstallation:

```
sudo service metasploit stop
```

In the worse case, uninstall metasploit completely and install it again from scratch.